# How to pass large no.of characters in java string value

Tags: java, spring, string, selenium, automation

How to pass large no.of characters in string value. Usually we pass  ***private final String title="Test String"***. But how to pass the below value in string.

```
**Test HTML code to insert** 

<div id="dededededededede">
Fill out my <a href="https://google.google.com/forms/z1dededede43434niu3pq">frfrtgte form</a>.
</div>

'autoResize':true,
'height':'575',
'async':true,
'host':'dede.com',
'header':'sdedew',
'ssl':true};

s.src = ('https:' == d.state.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'secure.deded.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
try { z1pmdedefr443434frfpq = new googleForm();z1pdedede4343434u3pq.initialize(options);z1pmkdedede434343niu3pq.display(); } catch (e) {}};
var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');</script>
```

Comment: convert to using one type of quote.  Then use other to enclose.  If you want the line breaks, use "\n".

Comment: You mean instead of double quote, you're telling to use single quote? If you don't mind can you please add sample piece of code here. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried Raw String Literals in Java, check out this link https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/raw-strings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newer Java<sup>**1**</sup> you can use [Text Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) like:

```
String text = """
        **Test HTML code to insert** 
        
        <div id="dededededededede">
            Fill out my <a href="https://google.google.com/forms/z1dededede43434niu3pq">frfrtgte form</a>.
        </div>
        
        'autoResize':true,
        'height':'575',
        'async':true,
        'host':'dede.com',
        'header':'sdedew',
        'ssl':true};
        
        s.src = ('https:' == d.state.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'secure.deded.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
        s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
            var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
            try { z1pmdedefr443434frfpq = new googleForm();z1pdedede4343434u3pq.initialize(options);z1pmkdedede434343niu3pq.display(); } catch (e) {}};
        var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
        })(document, 'script');</script>
        """;
```

In short: allows quotes and line separators; indentation of closing `"""` is important - defines how many spaces at start of line will be deleted. See also [JEP 368](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/368) or the corresponding chapter of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).

---

*Alternative* if Text Blocks are not available (not-so-new Java versions):

- line separator must be added to text: `\n`, or `\r\n` for Windows or just the result of `System.lineSeparator()`;
- double quotes must be escaped: `\"`;
- backslashes must also be escaped (if present): `\\`;
- multiple lines can/should be used to improve readability

Example:

```
String text = ""   // the empty string here is just for nicer formatting
        + "**Test HTML code to insert**\n"
        + "<div id=\"dededededededede\">\n"
        + "  Fill out my <a href=\"https://google.google.com/forms/z1dededede43434niu3pq\">frfrtgte form</a>.\n"
        + "</div>\n"
        + ...
        + "})(document, 'script');</script>";
```

<sup>Note: the compiler creates one single (*big*) string literal, no concatenation is executed at runtime despite `+` being used</sup>

---

**1** Java 15 or later, Preview Feature in Java 14

Comment: I'm getting error as: 
Text block literals are not supported at language level '11'

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan Java 11 doesn't have support for this.  As the answer states, need Java 15.